# RegEx / computer theory - construct a regEx in alphabetical order

Tags: regex, theory

In my grammars - Computer theory class I am trying to create a regular expression in alphabetical order(a-z)

```
l = {a, b, x, y, z, i, o, u, e, c}
```

This is what i have come up with using the kleene closure

```
aeiou(x*, y*, z*, i*, o*, u* e*)
```

With the kleene close *  thats zero or more so that should force abceioxyz?

We have not been learning this type of form

```
[^abc]
```

am i on the right track?

Comment: I don't know about the Kleene Closure, but nothing up there looks like a reasonable regex syntax, except for the thing you are not learning. `[^abc]`.  which wouldn't apply anyway.

Comment: I am studying computer theory and grammars a prelude to a compiler class where we learn how to make a programming language and a compiler.

Comment: well I figured you were in a CS curriculum, but ... I think that's irrelevant to the point at hand here - none of the hieroglyphics you included in your post are regex.

Comment: @Cheeso I don't think you know what a regular expression is:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to capture strings with the following format:

- The string contains any number of `a`'s, afterwards any number of `b`'s, then any number of `c`'s, and so on...

Let's consider a derived example: We want all strings consisting of `0` and `1` and that has all `0`'s before `1`'s: Therefore, we can simply write `0*1*`. Now try to adapt the pattern for more complex alphabets.

Comment: So, i arrange them in the order i need them! So, my above example could work.

Comment: @icelated Correct, you arrange them in the order you need them. But I don't get hundred percent how your above examples resemble this thought...

Answer (score 0):

the word must be in alphabetical order, so if it contains any a's, they surely must be at the front.
likewise, if it contains any b's , they must come after the a's, and nothing can come in between the a's and b's

so we have: `a*b*...`

and so a pattern emerges.

Comment: disregarding case, 'B' is in alphabetical order, is it not? so is 'xyz' for that matter.

Comment: @manojlds: Perhaps the most clearly formulated and pertinent question I've read all day. And a good one, at that!